# Is there a maximum number of verbs we can use in a row in a single sentence?

Tags: gramática, verbos, perífrasis

What is the maximum number of verbs you can think of to be used in a single sentence, in a row without using a list?

For example:

> Ella ha estado demostrando llorar en sus actuaciones.

I was asked this question and my maximum is 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean non-unique verbs, I think there is no limit, besides common sense, intelligibility, and what is necessary for the meaning of the sentence. One could make a long chain like this:

> Ella intenta evitar intentar evitar intentar evitar...hacerlo (She tries to avoid trying to avoid trying to avoid doing it)

Or, after all, if one can say, "quiere querer hacerlo," certainly "quiere querer querer hacerlo" makes sense, and so on.

But even with unique verbs, it is easy to make a longer chain.

> Ella debería haber intentado estar evitando demostrar llorar en sus actuaciones (She should have tried to be avoiding demonstrating crying in her performances).

Comment: Para aclarar, puede traducir las frases a Inglés?

Answer (score 1):

Sé dificulta responderte. Intentaria responder, tratando hacerte entender, diciendote: Sigue preguntando.

Generalizando sé dificulta responder intentando ayudarte iria insistiendo hacerte entender diciendote, debes seguir preguntando.

Porque la verdad el español no lo inventaron para hablar asi... XD nuevo record LOL

Comment: En realidad esa expresion consiste en dos o tres oraciones, de las que la mas larga tendria 8 verbos de varias formas (o mas bien 6).

Comment: Ahh con que asi es la cosa... Entonces yo la edito:

Comment: Interesante contribución, pero no responde a la pregunta (y de momento sale en las colas de revisión como "low quaility"). Creo que algunos usuarios no se molestaron en entender el concepto y tu contribución queda como una mala respuesta de robot o google translate. Mi recomendación es poner al principio o al final una breve explicación que diga "el límite es tu imaginación".